# How to update NULL values within all columns to 0 for SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I'm querying BigQuery data and wanted to change a lot of these NULL values to 0 for calculation. As far as I can google, there is no way to update automatically in SQL?

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) date,  
  channelGrouping AS channel,
  sum(totals.visits) visits, 
  CASE WHEN sum(totals.visits) > 0 
  THEN sum(totals.transactions)/ sum(totals.visits)
  ELSE 0 
  END as conversion_rate, 
  sum(totals.transactions) as transaction, 
  sum(totals.transactionRevenue) as revenue, 
  sum(totals.transactionRevenue)/ sum(totals.transactions) as aov
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
GROUP BY date, channel
ORDER BY transaction desc 
LIMIT
  100
```

Coming from Pandas library of Python, this seems very limiting. The only solution I can see is:

```
UPDATE table SET column1='' WHERE column1 IS NULL
UPDATE table SET column2='' WHERE column2 IS NULL 

etc.
```

Or would I need to use:

```
SELECT ISNULL(col1, 0 ) FROM table1
```

There are no columns where all its values are NULL so would the 1st solution work? And would the 2nd solution require another subquery?

Comment: What `NULL` values?  It is unclear what you are referring to.

Comment: If all you're doing is summing the values then being `NULL` is equivalent to being `0`, so no need to do anything. Otherwise your first solution is fine although presumably you want `UPDATE table SET column1=0 WHERE column1 IS NULL`

Comment: I've used `COALESCE( col1, 0 )` in SQL Server. A cursory glance at Google query suggests a similar mechanism is available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run the query you posted, I see these results:

[image]

I guess the goal of the question is to get these results instead:

[image]

To get those results with 0s instead of `null`, I did this:

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) date,  
  channelGrouping AS channel,
  sum(totals.visits) visits, 
  IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(sum(totals.transactions),sum(totals.visits)),0) conversion_rate, 
  IFNULL(sum(totals.transactions),0) as transaction, 
  IFNULL(sum(totals.transactionRevenue),0) as revenue, 
  IFNULL(sum(totals.transactionRevenue)/ sum(totals.transactions),0) as aov
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
GROUP BY date, channel
ORDER BY transaction desc 
LIMIT
  100
```

Note that I'm using `IFNULL()` and also `SAFE_DIVIDE()` - the latter one protects from dividing by 0.

Comment: Thank you I had no idea safe dvide existed!